# Execute huge sql file

Tags: php, mysqli, symfony-2.7

I'm trying to create a function which create a "huge" sql file (10 MB) with lots of `INSERT` queries.

Generating the file is done, now I'd like to  execute the sql.

In PHP, I would do:

```
$connexion = new mysqli([...]);

if($connexion->multi_query(file_get_contents($filename)) === TRUE ){
    // ok ...
}else{
    //error
    exit;
}
```

The SQL is in a variable `$content` so I tried:

```
$connection = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');
$test = $connection->executeQuery($content);
                         //or prepare
$test->execute();
$test->closeCursor();
```

and no errors are displayed but neither is any data in database and I can't use DQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `$content` actually load? If so is the SQL in it valid?  Do you have error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$connection = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');
$connection->prepare($content);
$test = $connection->exec();
$test->closeCursor();
```

also check for errors and typo's in your SQL Syntax